# Https and chrome, my file doesn't turn green?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, https, ssl-certificate

I have made a simple facebook app with ssl certificate enabled. Now the strange thing is my file doesn't parse secure in Chrome. In Firefox, IE8 (on PC) and Safari, Firefox (on Mac) it does parse as secure.

Is this a known issue with Chrome? Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What do the chrome developer tools tell you? Is there a network connection going over http and not https?
- Also try to browse in incognito mode, this should disable all your plugins in the normal case. Sometimes plugins cause a lot of pain when developing Facebook apps.
- If initializing the FB api try this:

  ```
  FB._https = true;
  FB.init({
      appId       : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
      status      : true,
      cookie      : true,
      oauth       : true
  });
  ```

Comment: tx good building blocks ;) I don't use chrome dev tools to its potential, just for CSS testing. Point 2 good one, will keep that in mind. The third one i use already. IBtw opening a new tab fixed my problem.

Comment: [edit] HMMM, it still buggy as the page isn't secure now???? only in incognito mode it does work

Comment: Well, than it's one of your plugins. Try to deactivate one at each time to find out, which one it is and if you can live with it: chrome://extensions/